# Recursion Query to get Children and its grandchildren

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one mapping table:

```
Code     Parent_code   Position
--------------------------------
H1       Null          Root
H11      H1            Parent
H111     H11           Parent
H1111    H111          Leaf
H1112    H111          Leaf
```

One more table which stores amount for leaf level code

```
Code   Amount
-------------
H1111  100
H1112  200
```

i.e amount is stored at only leaf position

I want to write the query through which the data at leaf level will get rolled up to its parents and ultimately to its root.

Output will look like below

```
Code   Amount
-------------
H1     300
H11    300
H111   300
H1111  100
H1112  200
```

Also if I select H1 that is root then output should be its children and its grandchildren.
Same if I select H11 i should get the output as H111 And children of H111

Comment: Can you upload a small SQL statement that would create a table and load in some sample data? It is very hard to read your text statements

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916597/sql-server-recursive-query)

Comment: Not a duplicate as this question requires the code to sum the resulting Amount. Enough of a quirk to differentiate the query

Answer (score 1):

a recursive common table expression should be able to give you the data you need. A good question/answer on this site is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159192/sql-server-2008-cte-recursion).

A quick example that may help you is this:

```
create table #Code
(
Code varchar(20),
Parent_Code varchar(20)
)
go
insert into #Code (Code, Parent_Code)
select 'H1', null
union
select 'H11', 'H1'
union
select 'H111', 'H11'
union
select 'H1111', 'H111'
union
select 'H1112', 'H111'
union
select 'H12', 'H1'
union
select 'H121', 'H12'
go
create table #CodeAmount
(
Code varchar(20),
Amount decimal
)
go
insert into #CodeAmount (Code, Amount)
select 'H1111', 100
union
select 'H1112', 200
union
select 'H121', 50

go

with CodeAmountRollup(Code, Parent_Code, Amount)
as
(
    select c.Code, c.Parent_Code, ISNULL(ca.Amount, 0) as Amount from #Code c inner join #CodeAmount ca on c.Code = ca.Code
    union all
    select c.Code, c.Parent_Code, Amount as Amount from #Code c inner join CodeAmountRollup car on c.Code = car.Parent_Code     
)
--select * from CodeAmountRollup
select Code, sum(Amount) as Amount from CodeAmountRollup group by Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of some SQL I wrote recently for a similar scenario, where I need to return all licensee and ordered by the level of licensee. Hopeful this might explain the concept.

```
WITH LicenseeEntity (iLicenseeId, vcLicenseeName, vcTradingName,iLicenseeType,iLicenseeStatus, iOwnerLicenseeId, Level)
    AS
    (
        -- Anchor Licensee definition
        SELECT l.iLicenseeId, l.vcLicenseeName, 
               l.vcTradingName,l.iLicenseeType,l.iLicenseeStatus, 
               l.iOwnerLicenseeId, 1 AS Level
        FROM Licensee (nolock) AS l
        WHERE iOwnerLicenseeId IS NULL

        UNION ALL
        SELECT l.iLicenseeId, l.vcLicenseeName, 
               l.vcTradingName,l.iLicenseeType,l.iLicenseeStatus, 
               l.iOwnerLicenseeId, 1 AS Level + 1
        FROM Licensee (nolock) AS l
        INNER JOIN LicenseeEntity AS le ON l.iOwnerLicenseeId = le.iLicenseeId
    )

    SELECT *  FROM LicenseeEntity le
```